# how to merge/join/concat/align two dfs with different time interval index and size in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Much written about this topic, but I still can't figure this one out:

I have df1 with unevenly time spaced rows like:

```
Time                   a  
2015-04-07 09:09:48    185.25
2015-04-07 09:30:50    190.50
2015-04-07 09:31:07    187.00
2015-04-07 09:35:23    190.60
2015-04-07 09:47:43    185.30
```

Then I have a much larger df2 also with unevenly spaced rows like:

```
time                 b      c      
2016-06-08 09:09:00  32.30  32.80
2016-06-08 09:09:48  32.35  32.89
2016-06-08 09:24:22  32.30  32.81
2016-06-08 09:30:50  32.40  32.84
```

I want to make a new df with every row in df1 with the time-corresponding row from df2 if any.

Expected outcome:

```
Time                       a        b       c
    2015-04-07 09:09:48    185.25   32.35   32.89
    2015-04-07 09:30:50    190.50   32.40   32.84
...
```

Is it possible to resample on custom frequency, i.e. df1.index?

Any hints or clues most welcome:)

**UPDATE**

One issue less to handle, I got rid of duplicate entries in df2:

```
df2[~df2.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

I'm looking for a pandas solution please. 
Example  above updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if pandas has any library, but this should be able to easily solved using a dictionary.

Build dict_1 from df1 and dict_2 from df2 with time as the key, then:

```
for time_key in dict_1:
    if time_key in dict_2:
       dict_1[time_key]['b'] = dict_2[time_key]['b']
       dict_1[time_key]['c'] = dict_2[time_key]['c']
```

Comment: What if there are multiple rows in dict_2 corresponding to time_key in dict_1 ?

Comment: In the for loop where you construct dict_2, overwrite the previous entry with newer one.